# How to force job to exit in GitHub Actions step

Tags: github-actions

I want to exit a job if a specific condition is met:

```yaml
jobs:
  foo:
    steps:
      ...
      - name: Early exit
        run: exit_with_success # I want to know what command I should write here
        if: true
      - run: foo
      - run: ...
 ...
```

How can I do this?

Comment: I don't think that is possible, but you can set a condition that would skip each step https://help.github.com/en/actions/reference/context-and-expression-syntax-for-github-actions

Answer (score 66, accepted):

There is currently no way to exit a job arbitrarily, but there is a way to allow skipping subsequent steps if an earlier step failed, by using [conditionals](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/learn-github-actions/expressions):

```
jobs:
  foo:
    steps:
      ...
      - name: Early exit
        run: exit_with_success # I want to know what command I should write here
      - if: failure()
        run: foo
      - if: failure()
        run: ...
 ...
```

The idea is that if the first step fails, then the rest will run, but if the first step doesn't fail the rest will not run.

However, it comes with the caveat that if any of the subsequent steps fail, the steps following them will still run, which may or may not be desirable.

---

Another option is to use [step outputs](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/reference/context-and-expression-syntax-for-github-actions#steps-context) to indicate failure or success:

```
jobs:
  foo:
    steps:
      ...
      - id: s1
        name: Early exit
        run: # exit_with_success
      - id: s2
        if: steps.s1.conclusion == 'failure'
        run: foo
      - id: s3
        if: steps.s2.conclusion == 'success'
        run: ...
 ...
```

This method works pretty well and gives you very granular control over which steps are allowed to run and when, however it became very verbose with all the conditions you need.

---

Yet another option is to have two jobs:

- one which checks your condition
- another which depends on it:

```
jobs:
  check:
    outputs:
      status: ${{ steps.early.conclusion }}
    steps:
      - id: early
        name: Early exit
        run: # exit_with_success
  work:
    needs: check
    if: needs.check.outputs.status == 'success'
    steps:
      - run: foo
      - run: ...
 ...
```

This last method works very well by moving the check into a separate job and having another job wait and check the status. However, if you have more jobs, then you have to repeat the same check in each one. This is not too bad as compared to doing a check in each step.

---

***Note:*** In the last example, you can have the `check` job depend on the outputs of multiple steps by using the [object filter](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/reference/context-and-expression-syntax-for-github-actions#object-filters) syntax, then use the [`contains`](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/reference/context-and-expression-syntax-for-github-actions#contains) function in further jobs to ensure none of the steps failed:

```
jobs:
  check:
    outputs:
      status: ${{ join(steps.*.conclusion) }}
    steps:
      - id: early
        name: Early exit
        run: # exit_with_success
      - id: more_steps
        name: Mooorreee
        run: # exit_maybe_with_success
  work:
    needs: check
    if: !contains(needs.check.outputs.status, 'failure')
    steps:
      - run: foo
      - run: ...
```

Furthermore, keep in mind that "failure" and "success" are not the only conclusions available from a step. See [`steps.<step id>.conclusion`](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/reference/context-and-expression-syntax-for-github-actions#steps-context) for other possible reasons.

Comment: I tried with object filter syntax. However, I'm using strategy matrix and your code with wildcard doesn't work. I found nothing related this in the doc. Do you know if anything is different for strategy matrix? For reference I'm getting this error `Error: Fail to evaluate job outputs
Error: The template is not valid. .github/workflows/build.yml (Line: 54, Col: 19): A sequence was not expected`.

Comment: @It'sK that kinda makes sense because `steps.*.conclusion` will evaluate to a list of conclusions, whereas the [docs](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/reference/workflow-syntax-for-github-actions#jobsjob_idoutputs) state that output must be a string. Try changing it to `join(steps.*.conclusion)`, and see if that works for you. Let me know so that I can properly update the answer

Comment: I've tested but strangly the output of multiple steps with `join(steps.*.conclusion)`  result into just only  `success`. Not getting conclusion of every step. FYI one step succeeds, one fails and one is skipped.

Comment: @It'sK that sounds like a bug. Please report it if you can

Comment: These are all creative but inconvenient workarounds for a feature Github should simply provide by now. The ticket is here, please upvote: https://github.com/actions/runner/issues/662

Answer (score 20):

The `exit` behavior can be achieved with `gh run cancel` and `gh run watch` commands:

```
- name: Early exit
  run: |
    gh run cancel ${{ github.run_id }}
    gh run watch ${{ github.run_id }}
  env:
    GITHUB_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}
```

The `watch` is required since cancellation will not abort immediately.

You may need `actions: 'write'` permission added for the job, something like:

```
permissions:
  ...
  actions: 'write'
```

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for to skip a step/job and also mark it as skipped, not success or failed. +1

Comment: I used this as well, I think this is currently (in early 2023) the best option for achieving this (other than breaking your workflow into different jobs). 

FYI for folks: The overall action shows as cancelled/neutral, but the logging within the workflow run says "errors occurred". Not perfect, but workable.

Comment: It cancels the whole workflow. And mark the whole workflow as cancelled

Comment: Thank you for this workaround. 
Not ideally because it marks workflow as canceled and sends a notification email which we cannot suppress AFAIK.

Comment: is there a way to mark the workflow as a success after the cancellation

Comment: @SDIDSA not easily as far as I know. You could try experimenting with https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/workflow-syntax-for-github-actions#jobsjob_idstepscontinue-on-error

Comment: I end up with this error "Could not find any workflow run with ID XXX" and the workflow is marked as failed, am I missing something ?

Comment: @NicolasBraun hard to tell without looking on a whole file, but it could be permissions related.

Comment: @evgeny.myasishchev I have write permissions for content, pages, id-token and actions set at the root level of the workflow file, then i'm using your exact code.

Answer (score 3):

I just did this by running `exit 1`

```
job:
  runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: 'Stage 1'
        run: |
          if [[ "${{ github.event.head_commit.message }}" =~ \[run-stage-2\] ]];
          then
            echo "Valid commit message detected. stage 2 will run."
          else 
            echo "Valid commit message not detected. stage 2 will not run."
            exit 1
          fi
      - name: 'Stage 2'
        run: <whatever>
```

So here, stage 1 one checks to see if the commit message contains `[run-stage-2]`. If it does, stage 1 will complete and stage 2 will begin; but it if doesn't, `exit 1` is called and the workflow will fail.

Answer (score 1):

If the other posted answers did not solve your problem then, you could consider creating a job that determines which jobs should be run and which should be skipped.
This solution makes use of [job outputs](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-jobs/defining-outputs-for-jobs).
Here is an example:

```yaml
jobs:
  planner:
    name: Determine which jobs to run
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    # To keep it simple name the step and output the same as job
    outputs:
      foo: ${{ steps.foo.outputs.should-run }}

    steps:
      # Checkout if necessary to determine whether 'foo' needs to run
      # - uses: actions/checkout@v4

      - name: Mark foo job as 'to be run'
        id: foo
        # Replace 'true' with your condition
        run: echo "should-run=true" >> $GITHUB_OUTPUT

  foo:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    needs: planner
    # Skip this job when condition not met
    if: needs.planner.outputs.foo == 'true'

    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v4
      # ...
```

*An example use case for this approach would be when you have an expensive job which can be skipped if the output is the same. For example running nightly tests against **latest** tag, but **latest** tag has not changed.*