# Get Github Action to fail when R throws an error

Tags: r, github-actions

I have a GitHub Action to build and deploy a webpage. However, it currently continues to deploy even when the build fails, which then breaks the webpage. How can I get the action to stop when R throws an error?

Here is an example of a run that should have failed: https://github.com/LukasWallrich/personal_webpage/runs/7148611428?check_suite_focus=true

Comment: I'd try setting `options(error = quote(q(save = "no", status = 1)))` to quit with a status level if there's an error.

Comment: Actually, you already get exit code 1 if you exit with an error.  So you need to look at questions like this one:  https://stackoverflow.com/q/60589373/2554330 to find how to end your job based on the exit code.